# Simple Vector2 structures (and interface)

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, interface

I built a couple `Vector2` structures (`Vector2` and `Vector2F`) for use with a particular project, so I'm mostly requesting best practices here.

The biggest concern is that I'm not making any assumptions I shouldn't be. I would like any comments that are relevant on the interface and whether it's too light, or if it's just right.

Do note: I know they should be auto-implemented properties where possible, but in this particular case I really don't want to use them like that.

```
public interface IVector2
{
    double R { get; }
    double Theta { get; }
    bool IsEmpty { get; }
}

public struct Vector2 : IVector2
{
    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    public Vector2(int x, int y) { _x = x; _y = y; }

    [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public bool IsEmpty { get { return this == Empty; } }

    public int X { get { return _x; } private set { _x = value; } }
    public int Y { get { return _y; } private set { _y = value; } }
    public double R { get { return Math.Sqrt((double)_x * _x + (double)_y * _y); } }
    public double Theta { get { return Math.Atan2((double)_y, (double)_x); } }

    public static Vector2 Add(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2) { return v1 + v2; }
    public static Vector2 Ceiling(Vector2F value) { return new Vector2((int)Math.Ceiling(value.X), (int)Math.Ceiling(value.Y)); }
    public override bool Equals(Object obj) { if (obj is Vector2) { return (Vector2)obj == this; } else { return false; } }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;

        hash = hash * 23 + _x.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + _y.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }

    public static Vector2 Round(Vector2F value) { return new Vector2((int)Math.Round(value.X), (int)Math.Round(value.Y)); }
    public static Vector2 Subtract(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2) { return v1 - v2; }
    public override string ToString() { return string.Format("({0},{1})", _x, _y); }
    public static Vector2 Truncate(Vector2F value) { return new Vector2((int)(value.X), (int)(value.Y)); }
    public static Vector2 FromRTheta(double r, double theta) { return new Vector2((int)(r * Math.Cos(theta)), (int)(r * Math.Sin(theta))); }

    public static Vector2 operator +(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2) { return new Vector2(v1.X + v2.X, v1.Y + v2.Y); }
    public static bool operator ==(Vector2 left, Vector2 right) { return left.X == right.X && left.Y == right.Y; }
    public static implicit operator Vector2F(Vector2 p) { return new Vector2F(p.X, p.Y); }
    public static bool operator !=(Vector2 left, Vector2 right) { return left.X != right.X || left.Y != right.Y; }
    public static Vector2 operator -(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2) { return new Vector2(v1.X - v2.X, v1.Y - v2.Y); }

    public static readonly Vector2 Empty = new Vector2(0, 0);
}

public struct Vector2F : IVector2
{
    private float _x;
    private float _y;

    public Vector2F(float x, float y) { _x = x; _y = y; }

    [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public bool IsEmpty { get { return this == Empty; } }

    public float X { get { return _x; } private set { _x = value; } }
    public float Y { get { return _y; } private set { _y = value; } }
    public double R { get { return Math.Sqrt((double)_x * _x + (double)_y * _y); } }
    public double Theta { get { return Math.Atan2((double)_y, (double)_x); } }

    public static Vector2F Add(Vector2F v1, Vector2 v2) { return v1 + v2; }
    public static Vector2F Add(Vector2F v1, Vector2F v2) { return v1 + v2; }
    public override bool Equals(Object obj) { if (obj is Vector2F) { return (Vector2F)obj == this; } else { return false; } }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;

        hash = hash * 23 + _x.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + _y.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }

    public static Vector2F Subtract(Vector2F v1, Vector2 v2) { return v1 - v2; }
    public static Vector2F Subtract(Vector2F v1, Vector2F v2) { return v1 - v2; }
    public override string ToString() { return string.Format("({0},{1})", _x, _y); }
    public static Vector2F FromRTheta(double r, double theta) { return new Vector2F((float)(r * Math.Cos(theta)), (float)(r * Math.Sin(theta))); }
    public Vector2F Invert() { return new Vector2F(0 - _x, 0 - _y); }

    public static Vector2F operator +(Vector2F v1, Vector2 v2) { return new Vector2F(v1.X + v2.X, v1.Y + v2.Y); }
    public static Vector2F operator +(Vector2F v1, Vector2F v2) { return new Vector2F(v1.X + v2.X, v1.Y + v2.Y); }
    public static bool operator ==(Vector2F left, Vector2F right) { return left.X == right.X && left.Y == right.Y; }
    public static bool operator !=(Vector2F left, Vector2F right) { return left.X != right.X || left.Y != right.Y; }
    public static Vector2F operator -(Vector2F v1, Vector2 v2) { return new Vector2F(v1.X - v2.X, v1.Y - v2.Y); }
    public static Vector2F operator -(Vector2F v1, Vector2F v2) { return new Vector2F(v1.X - v2.X, v1.Y - v2.Y); }

    public static readonly Vector2F Empty = new Vector2F(0, 0);
}
```

Also, example usage of the `IVector2` interface:

```
public static class VectorExtensions
{
    public static Direction? GetDirection(this IVector2 vector)
    {
        if (vector.R <= 0)
            return null;

        double theta = vector.Theta;

        if (Math.Abs(theta) <= Math.PI * 0.25f)
            return Direction.Right;

        if (Math.Abs(theta) >= Math.PI * 0.75f)
            return Direction.Left;

        if (theta >= Math.PI * 0.25f && theta < Math.PI * 0.75f)
            return Direction.Down;

        return Direction.Up;
    }
}
```

And the usage of that extension method:

```
        vector = Vector2F.FromRTheta(r, vector.Theta);

        Direction? d = vector.GetDirection();

        if (d.HasValue)
            Direction = d.Value
```

Comment: Are you using C# 6.0?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Well, I have *access* to C#6.0, but at the moment it still has to compile in a C#5.0 environment. (Damn XNA!) If you want to make C#6.0 specific suggestions, I'm all for it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Now I have full C#6.0. I managed to finagle XNA into Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: What's the purpose of the interface? How is it intended to be used? Can you give an example of a usage that would use the implementations interchangeably?

Comment: @craftworkgames Updated question with an example usage.

Comment: That was quick. I was going to mention extension methods, but it looks like you've already done it.

Comment: @craftworkgames Yep. That was the purpose of the interface, originally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> public override int GetHashCode()
> {
>     int hash = 17;
>
>     hash = hash * 23 + _x.GetHashCode();
>     hash = hash * 23 + _y.GetHashCode();
>
>     return hash;
> }
> ```

Calling `GetHashCode()` on an `int`, returns that `int`. For larger values of `_x` and `_y`, you are exposing yourself to overflow errors, unless you're building `unchecked`. Best is to instruct the compiler to just let the `int` overflow, resulting in a negative hash code instead of an exception:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 17;
    unchecked
    {
        hash = hash * 23 + _x.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + _y.GetHashCode();
    }
    return hash;
}
```

---

> ```
> public int X { get { return _x; } private set { _x = value; } }
> ```

I'd suggest one of two things:

- Make `_x` and `_y` be `readonly` and constructor-initialized
- Make `X` and `Y` be immutable auto-properties (C# 6.0 only)

The `private` modifier on the setter suggests mutability, which is a [bad, bad idea for a value type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/mutating-readonly-structs).

---

> ```
> public static Vector2 Add(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2) { return v1 + v2; }
> ```

Why make it `static`? Couldn't it be an instance method with a single parameter?

Readability-wise, I don't mind one-liner properties.

But one-liner *methods* (and operator overrides) are a problem. Get rid of that useless horizontal scrolling nightmare, and go vertical!

---

> ```
> public static readonly Vector2 Empty = new Vector2(0, 0);
> ```

Love it.

Comment: But I have a 1080p monitor, I have all this horizontal space I don't use. If not for codes then why made of big?

Comment: @EBrown well then, have the solution explorer pinned to the right, and have your unit tests pinned to the left, wide enough to see all the good descriptive method names ;-)

Comment: But then what good are multiple displays? :P

Comment: Would you read a book that was so wide you had to turn your head to read the lines? No. The same applies for code and content on the web. It's far easier to read thin columns of text. Newspapers have been doing it for decades.